# how to add dependencies gson for play framework

Tags: java, json, gson, playframework-2.2

I've added this to dependencies in plugin.sbt in play framework.

```
      "com.google.code.gson" % "gson" % "2.2.4"
```

but when i m trying  `Gson gson = new Gson();`
 i m unable to `import -> import com.google.gson.*;`

Comment: Why you wanna add to dependencies. Just add to your project library and add jar in build path.

Comment: thanks @hurricane. I create a lib/ directory and added gson jar.

Comment: Np man. If you apply my answer i will happy. Good Luck.

Answer (score 2):

You should add the below dependency to build.sbt

> "com.google.code.gson" % "gson" % "2.2.4"

I'm using play 2.6 and adding the above dependency worked for me. If you are using SBT, play java and eclipse follow the below steps,

1. **sbt**
   to enter into your sbt console
2. **clean**
3. **update**
4. **eclipse with-source=true**
5. **compile**
6. **run**