# Adding Gson to Play2 Framework

Tags: java, playframework-2.0, sbt

I've read through the [SBT Documentation](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/tutorial/Library-Dependencies.html) but am unable to find a proper answer for projects without Build.scala. This is a pure java based project.

Here is my build.sbt file -

```
name := """newproject"""

version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayJava)

scalaVersion := "2.11.1"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  javaJdbc,
  javaEbean,
  cache,
  javaWs,
  "com.google.code.gson" % "gson" % "2.2.4"
)
```

When I run make, everything compiles and resolves as expected but when I try to use Gson in my project, I get cannot find symbol. Manually importing "com.google.code.gson" doesn't work either.

I'm looking for a way to use Managed Dependencies and not Unmanaged (referring to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25615936/how-to-add-dependencies-gson-for-play-framework) post). Could someone please point me in the right direction? Is there a way I can have define App Dependencies without Build.scala?

**Update -**

I'm using IntelliJ and I can see com.google.code.gson in External Libraries. I tried to re-sync the project and invalidating the cache.

Answer (score 1):

Did you restart Play, or use the `reload` command after updating `build.sbt`?

Additionally, if you're using an IDE, you'll need to re-generate the IDE files to include a reference to GSON.  If you're using IntelliJ, use the `idea` command; for Eclipse, it's `eclipse`.

Comment: Please see update. I did "Synchronize" and it still isn't helping.

Comment: Hmm, weird.  Try using "File" > "Invalidate caches".

Incidentally, do you need Gson?  Play ships with Jackson for working with JSON.

Comment: Just tried that too. I must be missing something fundamental.

Answer (score 0):

in your project root directory , type

```
play ~idea
```

Comment: While this code block may answer the question, it would be a better answer if you could provide some explanation for why it does so.